# How to skip first item in a text file

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

So I have a work in progress program that will take a bunch of numbers (in this case, they're scores for a test) from a file, add them to an array, and then sort them by either descending or ascending order. I have managed to get this working using the following code

```
score_array = []

def opening_file():
     with open('scores.txt', newline='') as infile:
         reader = csv.reader(infile)
         for row in reader:
              score_array.extend(map(int, row))
def sorting_int():
     print ("How would you like to sort the scores? Press 1 for descending and 2 for ascending order..")
     userinput = int(input())
     if userinput == 1:
          score_array.sort(reverse=True)
     if userinput == 2:
          score_array.sort()
     print (score_array)

opening_file()
sorting_int()
```

In my 'scores.txt' file I have the following numbers 10,0,6,3,7,4 which all get sorted depending on what the user chooses. However, I want to be able to add in the name of a student. So for example, add in 'Alex' to the text file and it would skip the first item (which is the student's name) and instead just sort the numbers as usual. I'd like to have for example:
Alex,10,0,6,3,7,4
and sort only the numbers in descending/ascending order.

How would I go about doing something like this? I have tried too google for a solution, but I am afraid I've had no luck in finding one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your row parser to ignore cells that do not pass a test - isdigit in this case:

```
  for row in reader:
      score_array.extend(map(int, (v for v in row if v.isdigit())))
```

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few ways you can accomplish this, quick way would be using the pop/insert methods to manipulate the array prior to sorting like so:

```
a = ["corey", 1, 66.25, 333, 333, 1234.5]
tmp = a.pop(0)
# array with name removed, sort array at this point
print a
# add name back
a.insert(0,tmp)
print a
```

Comment: How would I implement that in my program?

Comment: you would pop array element 0 off before your sorting. You might want to backup though and do some reading on arrays and array manipulation.